# How do I size a wall sleeve for a through-the-wall air conditioner?

Tags: hvac

We are shopping for a through-the-wall air conditioner.  We do *not* currently have a hole in the wall with a sleeve in it.  We are trying to figure out what sleeve to buy.

The air conditioner we like is this [Keystone KSTAT12-1A](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Keystone-12-000-BTU-Energy-Star-Through-the-Wall-115V-Air-Conditioner-with-Remote-KSTAT12-1A/16440427?findingMethod=rr) sold at Walmart.  It's 20.25" deep but according to the manual 1.75" of that is the "front" part which is meant to stick out into the room.  Does that mean that I need a sleeve that is at least 18.5" deep or can I use a less-deep sleeve and have more of the unit stick out into the room?

I clipped this information from the manual.

[image: manual clipping]

It lists many sleeves that are less deep than 18.5".  So **either** it's OK to install this unit in a less-deep sleeve, **or** this is one of those pages which goes in every manual and you're supposed to make assumptions based on which model you bought.  Having never done this before and trying to read a very poorly-written manual I am not able to decide which of these reasons is the right one.

The real reason I'm asking is that the price difference is pretty big.  The Fedders sleeve that is 19 3/4" deep is commonly called the "Fedders B" sleeve and runs about $150.  The Sears/Kenmore/Carrier sleeve that is 18 5/8" deep is often called the "Carrier 51S" model and seems to be discontinued.  The next largest is a Fridgidaire EA108T which is 18" that sells on Amazon for $76.  So assuming it's OK for the sleeve to be less deep than the AC we can save 50% on the Fridgidare compared to the Fedders.

After making these purchases I am going to hand off the job to a handyman friend of the family, so I'm not seeking advice about the install.  I just want to make sure he has compatible AC and sleeve!

Comment: Best bet may be to ask the manufacturer directly.